# Download Over Cellular?

Tags: music, iphone, alarm

I have set up several alarms that use songs on my iPhone (iOS 6).

Whenever I modify one of those alarms (or create a new one with the now default setting of one of those songs) the phone asks me

```
Download Over Cellular?
Additional fees may apply when downloading songs over cellular.
(Cancel) (Download)
```

What does it want to download? The songs are on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

*Settings->General->Cellular* scroll down and set

**Use Cellular Data for:** *iTunes* = **ON**

This doesn't mean it's going to re-download anything for the alarm, just gets rid of the stupid warning.

Also you can check
*Settings->Itunes & App Stores*
**Use Cellular Data = ON**

If that doesn't make it go away, try resyncing library with itunes also.